# Stuck with a blank page while submitting mail() in php

Tags: php

i want to send two emails in background. It gets stuck with the blank page 
here is the code

after editing
i want to send two emails in background. It gets stuck with the blank page 
here is the code

i want to send two emails in background. It gets stuck with the blank page 
here is the code

i want to send two emails in background. It gets stuck with the blank page 
here is the code

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']) && preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $_POST['phnumber'])) {
        //regular expression for email validation
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phnumber'];
        $adults = $_POST['adults'];
        $children = $_POST['children'];
        $package = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $to = "yathraatravels@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Enquiry Request from Customer";
        $subject1 = "Enquiry Request from Customer";
        $message = '<table width="70%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><strong>Enquiry Request from Customer</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $name . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $phone . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>Email:</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $email . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>No of Adults</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $adults . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>No of children</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $children . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>Package</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $package . '</td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
        $message2 = "test email";
        $from = $email;
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";

        $headers1 = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers1 .= 'From: <' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";

        mail($from,$subject1,$message2,$headers1);

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

      }
    }
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);}
        else
            {
                header("Location: index.html");
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: A blank page in PHP when output is expected always means "go look in your error log" for the source of the fatal error. Turn up error reporting and `display_errors` always in development. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: To format a code block, highlight it and use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar, or `ctl-k`.  no need for extra line breaks.

Comment: Is $_POST['send'] set?

Comment: You're missing some close braces to match your `if` blocks at the beginning.

Comment: What is the referer superglobal set to? If it happens to be empty, then the redirect might not do what you want. In fact, I have experienced Chromium displaying a white page in this case.

Comment: Add a closing brace `}` just above your closing PHP tag `?>` and it should work.

Comment: added the closing brace.. now only the second mail() is working. The first mail() is not working

Comment: @Fred-ii- only one mail() is working

Comment: That's because there is nothing linked to `$message2` @AijuThomasKurian in `mail($email,$subject,$message2,$headers);` make up a message for it and it will work, just as you did for `$message` variable.

Comment: linked like this     $message2 = "test email"; but still not working

Comment: Yes exactly @AijuThomasKurian

Comment: @Fred-ii- still getting the second mail() only.. First one is not working.. not getting the string "test email"

Comment: Actually, I think you need to add an extra closing brace `}` you had 2x missing. @AijuThomasKurian I just noticed that now.

Comment: You also need to put `$email = $_POST['email'];` above your `if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])...` @AijuThomasKurian and all others under it.

Comment: this is the updated code.. still not working

Comment: I will post something shortly. @AijuThomasKurian

Comment: See my answer below. @AijuThomasKurian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few missing closing braces. One for your `if (isset($_POST['send']))` conditional statement and one for your `if (preg_match...)` conditional statement.

Plus, you did not have anything linked to the `$message2` variable in `mail($email,$subject,$message2,$headers);` so that has been added below.

I also added a few `else` conditional statements for both `(isset($_POST['send']))` and `if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])...` in case the PHP was accessed directly and show an error message.

Also, your `preg_match` was not properly located, so that has been relocated.

I have tested the following with success:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phnumber'];
        $adults = $_POST['adults'];
        $children = $_POST['children'];
        $package = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']) && preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $_POST['phnumber'])) {
        //regular expression for email validation

        $to = "yathraatravels@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Enquiry Request from Customer";
        $message = '<table width="70%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><strong>Enquiry Request from Customer</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $name . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $phone . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>Email:</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $email . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>No of Adults</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $adults . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>No of children</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $children . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%"><strong>Package</strong></td>
    <td width="85%">' . $package . '</td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

        $message2 = "test email"; // having it located here is IMPORTANT
        $from = $email;
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";

        mail($email,$subject,$message2,$headers);

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);}
        else
            {
                header("Location: index.html");

    // echo "OK"; // used for my testing purpose

            }

    } // end brace for if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])...

else { echo "Sorry bad email."; exit ; }

} // closing brace for if (isset($_POST['send']))

else { echo "Sorry you cannot do this from here. Please fill in the form."; exit; }
?>
```